# Facebook UI send

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, sdk, facebook-ui

I am using this facebook ui

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  to: the_users_ids,
  link: 'http://ngtv2.info/',
  name: 'I have a message here http://ngtv2.info/',
  caption: 'The caption',
  description: ('the descript'),
  picture: 'the/path/of/thumb_snow_leopard.jpg'
});
```

the send facebook ui appears, 
but when I click on the send button and then check the fb account that suppose to get the message, It does not appear on the message list.

I am having a internal server error,
and also this image [image]

Any idea?

I think my link is invalid, how can I make the link valid?

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

[image]

Thank you in advance,
King

Comment: Unless you'd like to expand the info in your question, you're not likely to get any response. Are you seeing any JavaScript errors or failed network requests, etc? Does the dialog do anything when the user clicks's Send? You haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: thanks for the response, I modified my question and put the error... really appreciate it Nathan Taylor. :)

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the send feature not working, but I'm pretty sure the `picture` argument for the ui method needs to be a fully-qualified URL to your resource. The send dialog runs in an iframe and will not be able to recognize a local path to an image.

Comment: Are you providing a redirect_uri anywhere? According to the documentation, it is 'Required, but automatically specified by most SDKs.' Have you tried specifying one in the arguments? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: I tried to specify it as you said but still it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing your application on localhost? That will not work.

Comment: Did you configure the canvas url and site url of your app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps to the same as the one you're testing it with? It should both be `http://ngtv2.info/`, otherwise you cannot use it as a link in your FB.ui method

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that the ids in the list are not friends of the user initiating the dialog. Or that the script is being run from a domain not listed in the app settings correctly.

Comment: I am sure that the id is my friend, might be the second one you mentioned. Can you please clarify what you said about the **"that the script is being run from a domain not listed in the app settings correctly."** Thank you

Comment: What URL is in the user's browser bar when the javascript is running?  What domain do you have in your app settings?  Are those two the same?

Comment: url when I am using the fb ui **http://ngtv2.info/mine** and **App Domain** is ngtv2.info

Comment: http://ngtv2.info/access/login Sends me to a login page.  Do you have an example of this on a non-secured place that we can test with?

Comment: the **"Use Facebook"** on the left bottom of the login page

Comment: maybe some other time....  we're here answering questions on our own time.  I'd prefer not to jump thru hoops.